# How does VCS such as SVN store files?

Tags: svn, version-control

As I am learning Git, I get to know that the **other** VCS systems like SVN usually store changes to a base version of files. So, as a logical deduction, if I want to check out the version 4 of the  file A, the SVN will patch the base version file on-the-fly with all the change sets commited until version 4 before delivering the verion I want?

The following picture may be helpful.
[image: Traditional VCS like SVN]

In short, only the base version file is stored **statically**, all the other versions are **dynamically** generated with base file and necessary change sets.

right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Subversion Design doc:

> Like many other revision control systems, Subversion stores changes as
>   differences. It doesn't make complete copies of nodes; instead, it
>   stores the latest revision as a full text, and previous revisions as a
>   succession of reverse diffs (the word "diff" is used loosely here –
>   for files, it means vdeltas, for directories, it means a format that
>   expresses changes to directories).

Important point is that, the *latest* revision is the base and (reverse) diffs are stored from that backwards.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/subversion-design.html#server.fs.struct

You can also look at the link to see how the commit gets stored in the repository.

Comment: The backwards storage model was used in the BDB filesystem in the past. More recent versions switched to a forward storage to allow a few other storage optimizations that proved to be very hard when storing this backwards.

Comment: In Git, this is not the case. A full snapshot of each version is stored with the meta data (such as change diffs). This way distributed VCS can be achieved. So SVN is more optimal in the sense of Space complexity but lack Time complexity in version resolving since it has to compute the change sets along the revision history.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of documentation about how Subversion stores its files, but the truth is that you really shouldn't know. Otherwise, you might be tempted to make these changes behind the repository manager's back.

The structure of the repository backend is a hot issue. Some groups say that this should be well documented and well understood in case there are problems, and the user can fix them. Others say that the structure should never be touched, and that the biggest issues usually arise from end users who think they know what they're doing, muck up the repository, and destroy everything.

Subversion repositories actually have two formats. One uses the FSFS file format (what most people use now), but originally, Subversion used Berkeley DB (BDB) for storing files. (It still can, but you now must specify it). In the future, Subversion will probably switch to SQLite or MySQL as its repository backend.

This will allow the Subversion developers to separate out the execution code from the repository structure. This will make adding new features much, much easier to do. For example, there has been a lot of hue and cry for an obliterate command. Unfortunately, from what Subversion developers have told me, it's simply impossible to do within the current FSFS file structure. A SQL based repository would have made this much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the background info.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't checkout a single file in Subversion. The smallest part you can checkout is a directory, but that will not change anything.

The best documentation about how SVN works and how things are stored can be read [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/subversion-design.html#deltas).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't use SVN much. So I hope someone can give me a confirmation of my guess.